# Entity Framework initialisation best practices

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I wish to ensure Entity Framework never overwrites or tries to create the database I am connecting to. It is an established database previously accessed by ASP website (visual basic script flavour). I've seen the convention where you pass "name=" into the base constructor like so...

```
//example 1    
public class SchoolDBContext: DbContext 
{
    public SchoolDBContext() : base("name=SchoolDBConnectionString") 
    {
    }
}
```

BUT I'd prefer to NOT have it HARDCODED (like the above), so perhaps...

```
//example 2
public SchoolDBContext(string ConnectionString) : base("name=" + ConnectionString) {
}
```

BUT I'd also like to be able to bug out if the string is empty...

```
//example 3
public SchoolDBContext(string ConnectionString) :  {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(ConnectionString) throw Exception("empty connection string");
    base("name=" + ConnectionString);        
}
```

Question 1: I'm unsure if the third bit of code does the same job as the second, does it? As the third example may call the parameterless construction first before calling base with the "name="

Question 2: Is there options available in the constructor that can be used to  configure EntityFramework more robustly?

I'm Using EF 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want EF to overwrite och create a new database every time you need to add the createinitializer class.

```
public class CreateInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<SchoolDBContext>{}
```

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx... 

CreateDatabaseIfNotExists: This is default initializer. As the name suggests, it will create the database if none exists as per the configuration. However, if you change the model class and then run the application with this initializer, then it will throw an exception.

Comment: I'm marking this correct, because I found my answer, by googling "CreateIntializer". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:**

Im not sure either. I need to admit I never saw something like that in examples. May you tell us/me your documentation source or how you came up with that Idea?

---

**Question 2:**
If you wan't a independence constructor, how about you try this?

```
    public SchoolDBContext()
        : base(ConnectionString == null ? "name=SchoolDBConnectionString" : WhateverYouDoIfItsWrong)
    {
        // Your code here! Lucky you
    }
```

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @Nnoel ah okay. Well, my code is the same as your example but... I would say smoother.

Comment: I'm using this also. +1

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [DbMigrationsConfiguration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrationsconfiguration(v=vs.113).aspx).

You can create a new class SchoolDbContextConfiguration-class which inherrit from it and set AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to false.

```
    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SchoolDBContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

And in your SchoolDbContext initialize as follows:

```
public SchoolDBContext(string ConnectionString) : base("name=" + ConnectionString) {
var init = new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<SchoolDBContext, SchoolDbContextConfiguration>(true);
        Database.SetInitializer(init);
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer. +1